# cloning form fields are populated with value from previous fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This function clones a set of text input fields inside a div, when the user clicks the add button:

```
function addRows(label, maxRows, minRows) {
  $('.add-' + label).live('click', function() {
    if ($("." + label + "-group").length < maxRows) {
      $('#' + label + '-template')
        .clone()
        .removeAttr('id')
        .insertAfter($(this).closest('.' + label + '-group'))
        .find('.minus')
        .show();
    }
  });
}
```

When the user fills in a field, then clicks the add button, it displays a new row of fields, but they are populated with the values the user entered in the previous row.

What is the best way to resolve this problem? I am thinking I could empty all input text fields for that instance of rows.

I just don't know how I'll clear the appropriate rows.

The field names are: `first_name[], last_name[], phone[]`

So when it clones those three fields to a new row, they will have the same name as the fields above.

When the user submits, I'll loop through each value in `first_name[], last_name[], phone[]`

Comment: Firstly, `live` is deprecated in the new version jQuery.  Better to use `on` or event delegation instead.

Comment: set .val('') on the input after you inject it

Comment: Also `The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes.`  Straight from the jQuery API.  Clearing the `.val()` as answered below would probably work.

Comment: @SethenMaleno `live` calls `on` in versions of jquery that support `on`, there's not really any reason to hassle people into changing `live` to `on`.

Comment: @SethenMaleno - what should I use in place of clone()?

Comment: @jbabey Read the documentation carefully in the jQuery API `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()`.  It's just better practice.

Comment: @Brad using `.clone()` is fine.  You have to clear the values of the inputs when cloned, though.  Did the answer below not help?

Comment: @SethenMaleno this seems to work $('#' + label + '-template').find('input').val('');

Comment: If you would, mark his answer as correct if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, call `val()` after other methods like `appendTo` or `insertAfter`

```
$('#' + label + '-template').clone().val("")...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnQhh/

Comment: $('#' + label + '-template').find('input').val('');

Comment: @Brad this makes original input value to none, you can call `val()` after cloning.